# Maximum call stack size error on recursive iterator

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with JavaScript, and just for learning purposes, I was writing a forEach iterator that can iterate through nested arrays or any other iterable object that include a `length property`.

This is what I wrote:

```
var forEach = function(obj, callback, options) {
  var options = options || {};
  var context = options.context || this;    

  if(!isEmpty(obj)) { // isEmpty function just evaluates `return !(!!obj.length);`
    for(var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {
      if(!isEmpty(obj[x]) && options.deep === true) {
        forEach.call(context, obj[x], callback, options);
        continue;
      }
      callback.call(context, obj[x]);
    }
  }
};
```

If I pass a nested array I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`:

```
forEach(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']], function(x) {
  console.log(x);
}, { deep: true });
```

But that only seems to happen if I check for length property in `obj[x]`

If I replace:

```
if(!isEmpty(obj[x]) && options.deep === true) {
```

For:

```
if((obj[x] instanceof Array) && options.deep === true) {
```

I will magically work. Hovewer, not only `Arrays` have a length property. `String` have it to, so It's not a wide approach.

How can I prevent the `RangeError` but still check for `length property`?

**EDIT:** I'm running the example on **NodeJS v0.8.12**

Comment: Consider that `'a'[0][0][0][0][0][0][0]...` is valid ad infinitum, and every value is type `string`.  If the type is `string`, then you should not recursively iterate it.

Comment: @mellamokb Yeah, I guess that makes more sense :)

Comment: @mellamokb Please post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that `'a'[0][0][0][0][0][0][0]...` is valid ad infinitum, and every value is type `string`. If the type is `string`, then you should not recursively iterate it.  Note also that `function` objects have a `length` property, and a `function` argument could be a self-reference to the `function` itself. This would cause another infinite recursion.   I think it would probably make more sense to handle different types differently instead of trying to develop a catch-all function.

You could also have a `maxLevel` property that limits the depth of the recursion, with a default value of, say, `10`. This way infinite recursion should not be easily possible.

```
forEach(['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']], function(x) {
  console.log(x);
}, { deep: true, maxLevel: 10 });

var forEach = function(obj, callback, options, level) {
    var options = options || {};
    var context = options.context || this;

    if (!level) level = 1;
    if (!options.maxLevel) options.maxLevel = 10;

    if (level > options.maxLevel) return;
    ...
        forEach.call(context, obj[x], callback, options, level + 1);
    ...
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bjpx5/